# 404 for image folder after redirect, but site works properly

Tags: apache, redirect, omeka

I have an Omeka S installation and it's all working properly, I made the redirect in apache in the sites-available folder, no problem with that.

In the same server I have a folder on the same level of my omeka s installation with the item images. When I want to load medias and I write the url of where to find the images I'll get a 404 error.
If I type `wget` and the url of where the images where to be found I get:

```
wget http://mysite.it/images/Albini
--2021-11-02 10:58:51--  http://mysite.it/images/Albini
Resolving mysite.it (mysite.it)... 127.0.1.1
Connecting to mysite.it (mysite.it)|127.0.1.1|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: https://myredirect/images/Albini [following]
--2021-11-02 10:58:51--  https://myredirect/images/Albini
Resolving myredirect (myredirect)... 160.78.46.107
Connecting to myredirect (myredirect)|160.78.46.107|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found
2021-11-02 10:58:51 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

How can I resolve this?

This is the config in 000-default.config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        
        ServerName myredirect.it
        Redirect / https://myredirect.it/

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/omeka-s
```

and this is the config in default-ssl.conf:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
        <VirtualHost _default_:443>

                ServerName myredirect.it
                ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

                DocumentRoot /var/www/html/omeka-s
```

Comment: I assume the `myredirect` in your log vs `myredirect.it` in your config is a typo?

Comment: "/images/Albini" - Is that meant to represent a physical image file? Why is there no file extension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out. I just needed to set an alias and gives permissions, without changing the DocumentRoot, like that (in the `000-default.conf` and `default-ssl.conf`:

```
AliasMatch "^/images/(.*)" "/var/www/html/images/$1"


<Directory /var/www/html/images/>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

It was well documented in https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> DocumentRoot /var/www/html/omeka-s
> ```
>
> ... I have a folder on the same level of my omeka s installation with the item images

I assume the folder `omeka-s` is your "omeka s installation" in which case, your `DocumentRoot` would seem to be set incorrectly for the URL you are requesting assuming `images` and `omeka-s` are two folders "on the same level".

With the document root as set above, a request for `https://myredirect.it/images/Albini` would be looking for `/var/www/html/omeka-s/images/Albini`, whereas it should presumably be `/var/www/html/images/Albini`.

For example, it should probably be set as follows instead:

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
```

And you will need to adjust the `<Directory>` container (assuming you have one) accordingly.

**UPDATE:** You presumably have a `<Directory>` container that follows that permits access, allows `.htaccess` overrides, sets `Options` etc. This `<Directory>` container should reference the correct document root also (not `/var/www/html/omeka-s`). For example:

```
<Directory /var/www/html>
    :
    :
</Directory>
```

Comment: All the assumptions are right. I wasn't thinking about the `DocumentRoot`, thank you very much! Just one thing: how can I adjust the `<Directory>` container?

Comment: @LaraM. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you, I don't have a `<Directory>` in that file, I added in `apache2.conf` this: `<Directory /var/www/html>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>
`
and restarted the server, but it doesn't work. Sorry for the ignorance

Comment: Well, you'll likely need a corresponding `<Directory /var/www/html>` container somewhere. It normally be logical to have this in the respective vHost container. What do you mean exactly by "doesn't work" - is this the same 404 response? Does `https://myredirect.it/` resolve as expected?

Comment: It returns as "Not found" when I try to access the website. It does that also if I put the `<Directory>` in the same file of the vHost config (the `000-default.config` file)

Comment: Also, sorry for the double comment, if I set the `AllowOverride All` I get the 404. I have the `a2enmod rewrite` already enabled, so I cannot understand what I am doing wrong